# Which one is better shared service or sending object via routeparams and why

Tags: angular, angular-services

I actually want to send an object to another page via routeParams but when I searched for it There are not many tutorials which suggest sending an object via routeParams

Which way is better to send the data??

I have a parent component and two sub components from sub component 1 to sub coponent 2 I want to send the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't send objects via route params, route params can only be strings. They are added to the URL. Technically you can serialize to a string and pass them using route params, but if there is no need to show them up in the URL you definitely shouldn't add them there. Shared service are the answer to almost every communication between components and directives, except direct static parent/child relations and a few other edge cases.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 2):

Services are recommended: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

You could also implement the child-to-parent and then parent-to-child workflow.